# I’m doing a research project requiring participants to look at a photo for ten seconds and then answer questions about small details in the photos

Tags: memory

I want to read up on some past studies that might’ve done something similar. Has anybody seen anything like this?

For example, one picture depicts a woman with a large, distracting necklace. A question that follows is “what color nail polish was the woman wearing?”

Comment: I believe you're referring to the term *[Inattentive Blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness)*.

Comment: Well, not quite inattentive blindness I think... there’s nothing outright unusual being introduced in the photos. It’s more like seeing how well people pick up on the small details.

Comment: Will any cues be given on what is it to be attended? If it's a pic with a lot of details, it's not necessary that the intended detail be even noticed.